# JSONGenerator How to output an object in the JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to output the following JSON:

```
result: {
    "x": 11,
    "y": 10,
    "actions": [
    ],
    "localConfigurations": {
         "local1": {},
         "local2":  {}
    }
}
```

I have the following code:

```
public class Configuration {
    private int fX;
    private int fY;
    private Actions[] fActions;
    private LinkedHashMap<String, LocalConfiguration> fLocalConfigurations = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @JsonProperty("x")
    public int getX() { return fX; }
    public void setX(int x) { fX = x; }

    @JsonProperty("y")
    // getter and setter for y

    @JsonProperty("actions")
    // getter and setter for actions

    @JsonProperty("localConfigurations")
    // getter and setter for localConfigurations
}
```

Below is the code that I am trying to use to output the JSON:

```
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(fOutputStream);

    generator.writeStartObject();
    generator.writeArrayFieldStart("result");

    if (configuration != null)
        mapper.writeValue(generator, configuration);

    generator.writeEndArray();
    generator.writeEndObject();
    generator.close();
```

However, my output turns out as:

```
result: [{
    "x": 11,
    "y": 10,
    "actions": [
    ],
    "localConfigurations": {
         "local1": {},
         "local2":  {}
    }
}]
```

I am not sure how I can achieve the desired output, without using the generator.writeArrayFieldStart. If I use only writeStartObject and dump the object Configuration, the JSON output throws some errors instead.
So, how can I get the output as I want?  thanks

Comment: You don't want an array, so don't use `writeArrayFieldStart` and `writeEndArray`. Why don't you just wrap your Configuration object into an object which has a `result` field of type Configuration, and write that object?

Comment: @JBNizet I am not sure what you mean by that suggestion. Can you provide an example?

Comment: `class ConfigurationResult { private Configuration result; //... }`, and then `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new ConfigurationResult(configuration));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open object, write property, write `Configuration` `POJO` and close object.

```
generator.writeStartObject();
generator.writeFieldName("result");

objectMapper.writeValue(generator, configuration);

generator.writeEndObject();
```